# A custom Button in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I have a `UITableView` with three section. I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. I want to put a button in the first section of my table view to handle an action.

How to can do this please?

Answer (score 1):

just create the button programmatically

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it in the section header (rather than a cell), you could:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section==0)
    {
        // create button and return it
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly, this method needs to not only create the button, but also the view that will hold that button. And I hope you don't mind, but I tried to clarify your answer with a brief intro.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the button directly into a `UITableViewCell` which is located in your first section. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can use for example:

```
    UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [yourButton setTitle:@"Click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourButton setFrame: CGRectMake( 20.0f, 3.0f, 280.0f, 33.0f)];
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:yourButton];
```

This example will look like this:

[image]

and will be places directly in the cell.